# Implement Android Share

Tags: android, service, share

I've seen plenty of example where people are sharing content from their application but I want to be able to share content with my application e.g. Users can press share via then Twitter.
Does anybody know any tutorials or guides? Also would you be able to share with a service? Would be a great feature to include :) Thanks

P.S. I dont want to share with Twitter/ Facebook, I want to share from apps like the browser to my app.

Comment: Use SDK for these and do little bit google it for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at these [Developer docs](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html)?
It has an example code snippet.

Comment: Thanks a lot, don't know know I had come across these :)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the SDK's / API's available for [Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/android/) and [Twitter](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) or else you could use `Intent.ACTION_SEND` to share text and images to the walls at Facebook and Twitter...

Comment: Sorry I dont want to share with Twitter/ Facebook, I want to share from apps like the browser to my app.

Comment: Could you be more precise with an example...?